# Override skin image files from an add-on?

Tags: css, firefox-addon, themes, xul

I'm building an add-on and thus far have done all styling in the add-on's css file (as opposed to a separate skin package). I now need to override the image files used for things like scrollbar handles and menu arrows.

Mozilla has a tutorial for overriding these using themes that are store in the `omni.jar` file, but we would prefer to avoid creating a separate theme to install when we're already installing an extension.

According to DOM Inspector a scrollbar gets it's style from `chrome://global/skin/scrollbars.css` and the rules are:

```
scrollbar {
  -moz-appearance: scrollbartrack-horizontal;
  -moz-binding: url("chrome://global/content/bindings/scrollbar.xml#scrollbar");
  cursor: default;
  background: url("chrome://global/skin/scrollbar/slider.gif") scrollbar;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

scrollbar[root="true"] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2147483647; /* largest positive value of a signed 32-bit integer */
}

scrollbar[orient="vertical"] 
{
   -moz-appearance: scrollbartrack-vertical;
}
```

I've tried poking at the scroll bars in my add-on with:

```
scrollbar{
   -moz-appearance:none!important;
   background-image:none!important;
   background:red!important;
   background-color: green !important;
   height:200px;
   border:3px solid green;
}

scrollbar slider{
   -moz-appearance:none!important;
   background:red!important;
   height:200px;
   border:3px solid green;
}

scrollbar, thumb {
   -moz-appearance: none !important;
   background:red!important;
}

scrollbarbutton {
   -moz-appearance: none !important;
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

But unlike other XUL elements that respond to overrides from the add-on's css file, these scrollbars just don't respond to anything. I'm wondering if part of the problem is that the scrollbars are inside the browser window?

How can skin images be changed or overridden from an add-on?